# Grab cell-dependent var from VC for use in UIActivityViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

My `UITableView` cells are populated with `JSON`. One of my key's values is an "ID" and it's necessary for constructing a url in my `UIActivityViewController`.

I'm not using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but instead I have a `UIButton` inside of each cell to activate the `ActivityViewController`. How can I detect which cell's share button was chosen and send that cell's "ID" to the `ActivityViewController` so that I can append it to my url?

This is my VC's string ready to be filled by the "ID".

```
var passID: String = ""
```

This is my `IBAction` and `UIActivityViewController` setup. My "`secondActivityItem`" is a `URL` that simply depends on the cell's "ID".

```
@IBAction func shareSheet(sender: AnyObject){

let firstActivityItem = "Help us meet a need this Christmas season! Can you meet this need?"
let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.domain.com/\(passID)")
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:Array!, error:NSError!) in

    if !completed {
        println("cancelled")
        return
    }
    if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
        println("twitter")
    }
    if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
        println("mail")
    }
}

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomCell

//Assign JSON keys to variables
var rowData: NSDictionary = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
var firstName=rowData["needFirstname"] as String
var descrip=rowData["needDescription"] as String
var city=rowData["needCity"] as String
var state=rowData["needState"] as String
var country=rowData["needCountry"] as String
var needID=rowData["id"] as String

return cell
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just use didSelectCellAtIndexPath? Otherwise, use the parent view of the button to get a reference to the cell, then call the tableView's indexPathForCell method.

Comment: For design purposes I need do it this way. There are two custom UIButtons (this being one) in each cell that perform segues. Mind throwing an answer in based on what you mentioned?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm mobile at the moment and can't effectively write code. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, some in part to the comment from Joshua Sullivan. However, I also used `tags` with a `IBOutlet` in my `CustomTVCell`.

Added this to my `JSON`:

```
    cell.shareButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

I added this to my `shareSheet` function:

```
    var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomCell

    if let sharebutton = sender as? UIButton {
        let rowData: NSDictionary = dataArray[sharebutton.tag] as NSDictionary
        cell.passedID = rowData["id"] as String
    }
```

This to my CustomTVCell.swift file:

```
    var passedID:String = ""
    @IBOutlet var shareButton:UIButton!
```